# Contiki RTOS hello-world fails

Tags: c, contiki

Hello there I am trying to execute the example programs included as part of the Contiki RTOS package. I tried executing the hello-world program by using the command: `make TARGET=cooja clean` and then typed `make TARGET=cooja`, and this resulted in the following output on the terminal:

```
I../../core/loader -I../../core/. -DAUTOSTART_ENABLE -c hello-world.c -o hello-world.co
hello-world.c: In function ‘process_thread_hello_world_process’:
hello-world.c:52:3: warning: variable ‘PT_YIELD_FLAG’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
ld   hello-world.co contiki-cooja.a  -o hello-world.cooja
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000008048094
contiki-cooja.a(log.o): In function `simlog':
/home/contiki/contiki-2.5/examples/hello-world/../../platform/cooja/sys/log.c:78: undefined reference to `strlen'
/home/contiki/contiki-2.5/examples/hello-world/../../platform/cooja/sys/log.c:83: undefined reference to `strlen'
/home/contiki/contiki-2.5/examples/hello-world/../../platform/cooja/sys/log.c:83: undefined reference to `memcpy'
/home/contiki/contiki-2.5/examples/hello-world/../../platform/cooja/sys/log.c:84: undefined reference to `strlen'
contiki-cooja.a(log.o): In function `printf':
/home/contiki/contiki-2.5/examples/hello-world/../../platform/cooja/sys/log.c:128: undefined reference to `vsnprintf'
make: *** [hello-world.cooja] Error 1
rm hello-world.co
root@ubuntu:/home/contiki/contiki-2.5/examples/hello-world#
```

Can someone please let me know as to where I am going wrong with the flow. I have made no changes to the original example codes and I intend to get the programs working on the COOJA simulator..thanks

Comment: I can see you are using Contiki version 2.5, which is _really old_. You should try using latest version from the git repository or the latest release, which is 2.6.

Comment: @errordeveloper thanks for the information I will update the contiki from version 2.5 to 2.6 and will try again..but please comment about the way I am trying to do a "make TARGET=cooja" command execution. thanks